# Недоступен сервис при запуске через IIS в режиме отладки

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Запускаю сервис ASP.Net Core в режиме отладки.
Порты вроде везде прописаны, в том числе в launchSettings:

`"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:48420/",
      "sslPort": 44364
    }`

Program:

`.UseUrls("http://localhost:48420/")`

По итогу такое сообщение:

`HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure
Common causes of this issue:
    The application process failed to start
    The application process started but then stopped
    The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port`

Answer (score 2):

Надо было перезапустить IIS. В Диспетчере задач завершить процессы IIS- запустить сервис.